# TCL data capture issue - expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I would like to know how to get the output of the previous command with TCL.

I have the following structure now:

```
exp_send -i $spawn_id "show port-access supplicant\r"

set buff ""
expect -regexp {".*"}
    expect -regexp ".*#" {send "show port-access supplicant\r"}
expect eof
```

*The command at this point returns the right info, but I don't know how to store it into a variable.

I was reading about the expect_out, but I couldn't make it work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expect buffer to do this.  Complete your 2 matches:

```
 expect -regexp ".#" {send "show port-access supplicant\r"}
 expect -regexp ".#"; #Match the prompt again after the device output returns
```

And then try:

```
 puts $expect_out(buffer)
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I get.
I'm getting the following output:

1234 -  end 
                                                                                                                                        Client_A# - 123
Client_A#  

I'm using puts "1234 - $expect_out(buffer) - 123"... I don't know why I'm not getting the right info

Output:

 Port Access Supplicant Status

       Supplicant     Held   Auth    Start  Max                            
  Port State          Period Timeout Period Start Port Identity            
  1    Authenticated  60     30      30     3     User
@niall-byrne

Comment: All my issue is Regex.. I'm adjusting the parameters now, thanks for give me the light!